# PhaserJS 3.0 How to place image in right bottom of the screen?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've tried to create a zone, attach image to it's and change displayed size of the zone, but it didn't work. this === Phaser.Scene

```
this.zone = this.add.zone(
   this.game.scale.width / 2,
   this.game.scale.height / 2,
   this.game.scale.width,
   this.game.scale.height,
);
Phaser.Display.Align.In.BottomRight(this.image, this.zone, -20, -20);
```

and on resize event
`this.zone.setDisplaySize(this.game.scale.width, this.game.scale.height);`

It places correct at start but doesn't work on resize. I double-checked that the event handler works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be easier to just set the Origin of your image to the bottom-right: `Image.setOrigin(1, 1);`.

Then just do `Image.setPosition(width, height)`, using the values that Phaser passes automatically to the resize event callback. No need for a Zone to do this at all, really.